# Using Questions in Arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get a quiz application to work, I have the array build with the questions and answers but I'm running into issues getting the next question to pop up after clicking the submit button. Here was so of the code so far any suggestions.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  function question(mascotImage, question, answer, choice1, choice2, choice3, choice4, choice5, secondquestion, secondanswer, secondchoice1, secondchoice2, secondchoice3, secondchoice4, secondchoice5) {
    this.mascotImage = mascotImage;
    this.question = question;
    this.answer = answer;
    this.choice1 = choice1;
    this.choice2 = choice2;
    this.choice3 = choice3;
    this.choice4 = choice4;
    this.choice5 = choice5;
    this.secondquestion = secondquestion;
    this.secondanswer = secondanswer;
    this.secondchoice1 = secondchoice1;
    this.secondchoice2 = secondchoice2;
    this.secondchoice3 = secondchoice3;
    this.secondchoice4 = secondchoice4;
    this.secondchoice5 = secondchoice5;
  }


  //Questions

  var question1 = new question("img/dinger.jpg", "What is my name?", "Dinger", "Wally the Green Monster", "Sluggerrr", "Orbit", "Dinger", "Lou Seal", "Who do I represent?", "Colorado Rockies", "Colorado Rockies", "Boston Red Sox", "New York Yankess", "Houston Astros", "San Diego Padres");


  var question2 = new question("img/slugger.jpg", "What is my name?", "Sluggerrr", "Simba", "Sluggerrr", "Pride", "Leo the Lion", "The Tiger", "Who do I represent?", "Kansas City Royals", "Detriot Tigers", "Chicago Cubs", "Washington Nationals", "Atlanta Braves", "Kansas City Royals");


  var question3 = new question("img/wally.jpg", "What is my name?", "Wally the Green Monster", "Phanatic", "Sully", "Raymond", "Irish Monster", "Wally the Green Monster", "Who do I represent?", "Boston Red Sox", "Boston Red Sox", "Tampa Bay Rays", "New York Yankess", "San Francisco Giants", "Philadelphia Phillies");


  var question4 = new question("img/Swinging_friar.jpg", "What is my name?", "Swinging Friar", "Mr. Met", "Phanatic", "His Holyness", "Swinging Friar", "Monk", "Who do I represent?", "San Diego Padres", "Minnesota Twins", "San Diego Padres", "Washington Nationals", "Texas Rangers", "Arizona Diamondbacks");


  var question5 = new question("img/orbit.jpg", "What is my name?", "Orbit", "Marvin", "Orbit", "E.T.", "Stro", "The Martian", "Who do I represent?", "Houston Astros", "New York Mets", "Cleveland Indians", "Chicago White Sox", "Houston Astros", "Milwaukee Brewers");


  var question6 = new question("img/fredbird.jpg", "What is my name?", "Fredbird", "Cardy", "The Oriole", "Freddy", "Jay", "Fredbird", "Who do I represent?", "St. Louis Cardinals", "Baltimore Oriole", "St. Louis Cardinals", "Atlanta Braves", "Toronto Blue Jays", "Minnesota Twins");


  var question7 = new question("img/Raymond.jpg", "What is my name?", "Raymond", "The Blue Dog", "Raymond", "Sea Monster", "Ray", "Wally", "Who do I represent?", "Tampa Bay Rays", "Miami Marlins", "Toronto Blue Jays", "Seattle Mariners", "San Francisco Giants", "Tampa Bay Rays");


  var question8 = new question("img/Lou.jpg", "What is my name?", "Lou Seal", "Lou Seal", "Louie", "Otter", "River Cat", "Sandy", "Who do I represent?", "San Francisco Giants", "Chicago Cubs", "Philadelphia Phillies", "San Francisco Giants", "Pittsburgh Pirates", "Los Angeles Dodgers");


  //The array

  var questionArray = [question1, question2, question3, question4, question5, question6, question7, question8];

  //Keeping track of question

  var questionCounter = 0;

  var currentQuestion = questionArray[questionCounter];

  function loadData() {
    $('#mascotImage').attr('src', currentQuestion.mascotImage);
    $('#q1a1').val(currentQuestion.choice1);
    $('#q1a1').after(currentQuestion.choice1);
    $('#q1a2').val(currentQuestion.choice2);
    $('#q1a2').after(currentQuestion.choice2);
    $('#q1a3').val(currentQuestion.choice3);
    $('#q1a3').after(currentQuestion.choice3);
    $('#q1a4').val(currentQuestion.choice4);
    $('#q1a4').after(currentQuestion.choice4);
    $('#q1a5').val(currentQuestion.choice5);
    $('#q1a5').after(currentQuestion.choice5);

    $('#q2a1').val(currentQuestion.secondchoice1);
    $('#q2a1').after(currentQuestion.secondchoice1);
    $('#q2a2').val(currentQuestion.secondchoice2);
    $('#q2a2').after(currentQuestion.secondchoice2);
    $('#q2a3').val(currentQuestion.secondchoice3);
    $('#q2a3').after(currentQuestion.secondchoice3);
    $('#q2a4').val(currentQuestion.secondchoice4);
    $('#q2a4').after(currentQuestion.secondchoice4);
    $('#q2a5').val(currentQuestion.secondchoice5);
    $('#q2a5').after(currentQuestion.secondchoice5);
  }

  loadData();

  $('#submitAnswer').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    checkAnswers();
  });

  function checkAnswers() {
    //.val() == currentQuestion.correctAnswer
    // user answers both
    // if question is correct increment correctCounter *note create correctCounter*
    questionCounter++;
    loadData();
  }

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Major League Baseball Mascot Quiz -- Alex Houle</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/grayscale.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/myStyles.css">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="text-center myOverrideHead row">
    <h1>Major League Baseball Mascots Quiz</h1>
    <h4>Alex Houle</h4>
  </div>

  <!-- QUESTIONS -->

  <div class="text-center row col-xs-4">

    <div class="row">
      <h4>What is my name?</h4>
      <ul>
        <li class="pager">
          <input name="mascotName" id="q1a1" type="radio" />
        </li>
        <li class="pager">
          <input name="mascotName" id="q1a2" type="radio" />
        </li>
        <li class="pager">
          <input name="mascotName" id="q1a3" type="radio" />
        </li>
        <li class="pager">
          <input name="mascotName" id="q1a4" type="radio" />
        </li>
        <li class="pager">
          <input name="mascotName" id="q1a5" type="radio" />
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="text-center row col-xs-4">
    <div class="row">
      <img id="mascotImage" src="" class="photo">
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="text-center row col-xs-4">
    <div class="row">
      <h4>Who do I represent?</h4>
      <ul>
        <li class="pager">
          <input name="teamName" id="q2a1" type="radio" />
        </li>
        <li class="pager">
          <input name="teamName" id="q2a2" type="radio" />
        </li>
        <li class="pager">
          <input name="teamName" id="q2a3" type="radio" />
        </li>
        <li class="pager">
          <input name="teamName" id="q2a4" type="radio" />
        </li>
        <li class="pager">
          <input name="teamName" id="q2a5" type="radio" />
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </div>

  <!-- SUBMIT BUTTON -->

  <div class="text-center myOverride row">
    <button type="button" id="submitAnswer" class="btn-primary">Submit</button>
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you only update `questionCounter` but not `currentQuestion` in your `checkAnswers()`-method.

I would propose to use a function for getting the current question instead of a variable:

```
function getCurrentQuestion() {
    return questionArray[questionCounter];
}
```

That way you don't need to update when `queryCounter` changes.

By the way, the name of constructor functions starts with a capital letter by convention.